# From a Windows Service running as LocalSystem, how to start a process as any local user without having the password?

Tags: c#, .net, process, windows-services, impersonation

I know that lot of similar questions have been posted, but without acceptable responses for me.

I have a Windows Service (in C#) running a Local System account. This service need to run processes with user accounts credentials (not only already logged ones). And users passwords can't be known by the service.

So the service need to start processes as a local user without having to specify the user password.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks.

Comment: If this were possible, it would be dangerous. Parts can be done, but not what you have asked.

Comment: What kind of process do you need to start? The service cannot have the credentials inside?

Comment: I'm not a C# developer, but if you ever manage to do this, i suggest you follow up by formatting your hard drive and burning your windows installation discs.

Comment: Under Unix systems, this is not a problem. 'root' user have rights to run processes with any identity without providing password. I'm just trying to do the same thing under Windows.
@NicoRiff Local users can be created, changed and removed after the installation of my service, so credentials can't be stored inside.